# How do I configure the SlickRun Magic Word to lock my computer?

Tags: lock

I want to setup a magic word in SlickRun to lock my computer like Win+L would do. Can someone please help me out with this request?

Comment: since it worked, don't forget to close the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have SlickRun use a keyboard shortcut.  MagicWords have to be assigned to programs, URLs, or shortcuts.  So, it doesn't seem all that intuitive at first.  However, with that said...

First, you create a shortcut to lock the workstation.

> 1. Right click anywhere on your desktop, and click/tap on New and Shortcut.
> 2. Type rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation and click/tap on Next.
> 3. Type Lock Computer for the name, and click/tap on Finish.

(from [sevenforums.com](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/13278-lock-computer-create-shortcut.html))

Now that you have a shortcut to it, you can use the [Slickrun setup](http://www.bayden.com/slickrun/1033/SlickRunSetup.htm).  You go into the Setup, and then into the [Magicword Editor](http://www.bayden.com/slickrun/1033/SlickRunSetup.htm#Editor).  You create a new MagicWord, and have it run the shortcut you just created.